# Pass initializer list to function for initialization of std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, list-initialization

In my Point header I have:

```
 15 template<typename real> class Point
 16 {
 17 public:
 18     // Constructors
 19     Point();
 20     Point(const std::initializer_list<real>&);
 21     Point(const std::initializer_list<real>&, const types::unitTypes);
 22     Point(const real, const real, const real);
 23     Point(const real, const real, const real, const types::unitTypes);
...
 43 private:
 44     std::array<real, 3> xyz_;
 45     types::unitTypes units_;
 46 };
```

Note that lines 20 and 44 show that the `Point` to should be able to be initialized with an `initializer_list` and I have private variable `std::array<real, 3> xyz_`. Now, I would like for my constructor of this to be something like the following:

```
 31 template<typename T>
 32 Point<T>::Point(const std::initializer_list<T>& xyz)
 33     : xyz_(xyz)
 34     , units_(types::au)
 35 {};
```

However, it doesn't seem like I'm able to construct the `array` from an `initializer` and if I try to move that modify that from `:xyz_(xyz)` to something like

```
 31 template<typename T>
 32 Point<T>::Point(std::initializer_list<T> xyz)
 33     : units_(types::au)
 34 {
 35     xyz_ = xyz;
 36 };
```

it is not able to overload `=` for operands `array` and `initializer`. Is there a better way to go about this that I can use invoke `Point<real>({x, y, z});` and initialize the `xyz_` array internally?

---

### Update:

I had tried to define `Point(const std::array<real, 3>&)` before but I get the following compilation error (essential parts extracted):

```
error: call of overloaded ‘Point(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’ is ambiguous
...
note: candidate: ‘aided::point::Point<real>::Point(const std::array<real, 3>&) [with real = float]’
...
note: candidate: ‘constexpr aided::point::Point<float>::Point(const aided::point::Point<float>&)’
...
note: candidate: ‘constexpr aided::point::Point<float>::Point(aided::point::Point<float>&&)’
```

The first is candidate is the one I am intending to use. Are the second two somehow copy constructors that are able to be invoked via an initialization with an initializer list?

Comment: After thinking of it more, why do you need an `initializer_list` (or `array`) constructor in the first place? `Point(const real, const real, const real)` should do something very similar.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - Yes, I have a method for this and it's how I've been using it so far. I'm trying to work on some optimization and wondering if storing my (x, y, z) values as an array in the underlying `Point` implementation will speed up the code. This Ctor gets used quite a bit so I'm trying to make it as lean as possible.

Also - FWIW, I found a thing I don't know about and want to learn more :)

Comment: It won't make a difference. The memory layout is the same, so it'll be optimized to the same thing. What's the question now though? If the `initializer_list` constructor was the only one, the solution would be to replace it with an `array` constructor. But since you already have a constructor from three doubles, the fix is to remove the list one altogether.

Answer (score 1):

`std::initializer_list` and `std::array` don’t cooperate as well as one would hope. Separate constructor arguments can give you a bit more flexibility, automatic template argument deduction and (also, to some extent) automatic choice of a type that can hold all the values:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename Real, size_t N>
struct Point {
  template <typename... R>
  Point(R &&...reals) : xyz_{static_cast<Real>(std::forward<R>(reals))...} {}

 private:
  std::array<Real, N> xyz_;

  template <size_t Head, size_t... Tail>
  void print(std::ostream &out, std::index_sequence<Head, Tail...>) const {
    out << xyz_[Head];
    ((out << ',' << xyz_[Tail]), ...);
  }

  friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Point &point) {
    out << typeid(Real).name() << ' ' << '[';
    point.print(out, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
    return out << ']';
  }
};

template <typename... R>
Point(R &&...) -> Point<std::common_type_t<R...>, sizeof...(R)>;
```

Now let’s test that↑ a bit and let’s not insist on *`Real`* too strongly:

```cpp
#include <complex>
#include "that_magic_point.h"

int main() {
  Point p0{1, 2, 3};                  // int
  Point p1{4., 5., 6.};               // double
  Point p2{7, 8., 9};                 // int, double -> double
  Point p3{10, 11, 12ll};             // int, long long -> long long
  Point p4{1};                        // int
  Point p5{2., 3.};                   // double
  Point p6{4, 5., 6u, 7};             // int, double, unsigned -> double
  Point p7{std::complex{1, 2}, 3};    // complex<int>, int -> complex<int>
  Point p8{4, std::complex{5., 6.}};  // int, complex<double> -> complex<double>

  // Caveat: This resolves (incorrectly) to complex<int>:
  // Point p9{std::complex{7, 8}, 9.};

  // Caveat: This will not compile (cast from complex<int> to complex<double>):
  // Point<std::complex<double>, 2> p9{std::complex{7, 8}, 9.};

  // Caveat: This is verbose:
  Point<std::complex<double>, 2> p9{std::complex<double>{7, 8}, 9.};

  std::cout << p0 << '\n'
            << p1 << '\n'
            << p2 << '\n'
            << p3 << '\n'
            << p4 << '\n'
            << p5 << '\n'
            << p6 << '\n'
            << p7 << '\n'
            << p8 << '\n'
            << p9 << '\n';
}
```

This↑ [seems to work](https://cpp.sh/?source=%23include+%3Carray%3E%0D%0A%23include+%3Ccomplex%3E%0D%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0D%0A%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0D%0A%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Anamespace+%7B%0D%0A%0D%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+Real%2C+size_t+N%3E%0D%0Astruct+Point+%7B%0D%0A++template+%3Ctypename...+R%3E%0D%0A++Point(R+%26%26...reals)+%3A+xyz_%7Bstatic_cast%3CReal%3E(std%3A%3Aforward%3CR%3E(reals))...%7D+%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A+private%3A%0D%0A++std%3A%3Aarray%3CReal%2C+N%3E+xyz_%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A++template+%3Csize_t+Head%2C+size_t...+Tail%3E%0D%0A++void+print(std%3A%3Aostream+%26out%2C+std%3A%3Aindex_sequence%3CHead%2C+Tail...%3E)+const+%7B%0D%0A++++out+%3C%3C+xyz_%5BHead%5D%3B%0D%0A++++((out+%3C%3C+%27%2C%27+%3C%3C+xyz_%5BTail%5D)%2C+...)%3B%0D%0A++%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A++friend+std%3A%3Aostream+%26operator%3C%3C(std%3A%3Aostream+%26out%2C+const+Point+%26point)+%7B%0D%0A++++out+%3C%3C+typeid(Real).name()+%3C%3C+%27+%27+%3C%3C+%27%5B%27%3B%0D%0A++++point.print(out%2C+std%3A%3Amake_index_sequence%3CN%3E())%3B%0D%0A++++return+out+%3C%3C+%27%5D%27%3B%0D%0A++%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename...+R%3E%0D%0APoint(R+%26%26...)+-%3E+Point%3Cstd%3A%3Acommon_type_t%3CR...%3E%2C+sizeof...(R)%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D++%2F%2F+namespace%0D%0A%0D%0Aint+main()+%7B%0D%0A++Point+p0%7B1%2C+2%2C+3%7D%3B++++++++++++++++++%2F%2F+int%0D%0A++Point+p1%7B4.%2C+5.%2C+6.%7D%3B+++++++++++++++%2F%2F+double%0D%0A++Point+p2%7B7%2C+8.%2C+9%7D%3B+++++++++++++++++%2F%2F+int%2C+double+-%3E+double%0D%0A++Point+p3%7B10%2C+11%2C+12ll%7D%3B+++++++++++++%2F%2F+int%2C+long+long+-%3E+long+long%0D%0A++Point+p4%7B1%7D%3B++++++++++++++++++++++++%2F%2F+int%0D%0A++Point+p5%7B2.%2C+3.%7D%3B+++++++++++++++++++%2F%2F+double%0D%0A++Point+p6%7B4%2C+5.%2C+6u%2C+7%7D%3B+++++++++++++%2F%2F+int%2C+double%2C+unsigned+-%3E+double%0D%0A++Point+p7%7Bstd%3A%3Acomplex%7B1%2C+2%7D%2C+3%7D%3B++++%2F%2F+complex%3Cint%3E%2C+int+-%3E+complex%3Cint%3E%0D%0A++Point+p8%7B4%2C+std%3A%3Acomplex%7B5.%2C+6.%7D%7D%3B++%2F%2F+int%2C+complex%3Cdouble%3E+-%3E+complex%3Cdouble%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A++%2F%2F+Caveat%3A+This+resolves+(incorrectly)+to+complex%3Cint%3E%3A%0D%0A++%2F%2F+Point+p9%7Bstd%3A%3Acomplex%7B7%2C+8%7D%2C+9.%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A++%2F%2F+Caveat%3A+This+will+not+compile+(cast+from+complex%3Cint%3E+to+complex%3Cdouble%3E)%3A%0D%0A++%2F%2F+Point%3Cstd%3A%3Acomplex%3Cdouble%3E%2C+2%3E+p9%7Bstd%3A%3Acomplex%7B7%2C+8%7D%2C+9.%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A++%2F%2F+Caveat%3A+This+is+verbose%3A%0D%0A++Point%3Cstd%3A%3Acomplex%3Cdouble%3E%2C+2%3E+p9%7Bstd%3A%3Acomplex%3Cdouble%3E%7B7%2C+8%7D%2C+9.%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A++std%3A%3Acout+%3C%3C+p0+%3C%3C+%27%5Cn%27%0D%0A++++++++++++%3C%3C+p1+%3C%3C+%27%5Cn%27%0D%0A++++++++++++%3C%3C+p2+%3C%3C+%27%5Cn%27%0D%0A++++++++++++%3C%3C+p3+%3C%3C+%27%5Cn%27%0D%0A++++++++++++%3C%3C+p4+%3C%3C+%27%5Cn%27%0D%0A++++++++++++%3C%3C+p5+%3C%3C+%27%5Cn%27%0D%0A++++++++++++%3C%3C+p6+%3C%3C+%27%5Cn%27%0D%0A++++++++++++%3C%3C+p7+%3C%3C+%27%5Cn%27%0D%0A++++++++++++%3C%3C+p8+%3C%3C+%27%5Cn%27%0D%0A++++++++++++%3C%3C+p9+%3C%3C+%27%5Cn%27%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A) and may generate the following output (modulo compilers’ RTTI naming differences):

```
i [1,2,3]
d [4,5,6]
d [7,8,9]
x [10,11,12]
i [1]
d [2,3]
d [4,5,6,7]
St7complexIiE [(1,2),(3,0)]
St7complexIdE [(4,0),(5,6)]
St7complexIdE [(7,8),(9,0)]
```

Solving some of the caveats outlined in comments using deep(er) template decomposition and specialization would be a nice exercise, but may not be worth the hassle.

Answer (score 1):

There is basically no problem to use a `std::initializer list` for your class. You just need to copy the data manually.

You can also check the number of parameters in the `std::initializer_list` and act accordingly. In my below example I used `assert` to check that.

You can also implement the rule of 3 or 5. Although not needed for this simple class. I added it just for demo purposes.

I also recomend to use parameters with default arguments. For this example, it will make life easier.

Maybe best is to show an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <cassert>

enum class types : int { au };

class Point {
    std::array<double, 3> coordinate{};
    types type{};
public:

    // Rule of five. Not needed in this case
    Point() {};
    Point(const Point& other) { coordinate = other.coordinate; type = other.type; }
    Point& operator = (const Point& p) { if (this == &p) return *this; coordinate = p.coordinate; type = p.type; return *this; }
    Point(Point&& other) noexcept { coordinate = std::move(other.coordinate); type = other.type; }
    Point& operator = (Point&& other) noexcept { coordinate = std::move(other.coordinate); type = other.type; return *this; }

    virtual ~Point() {};

    // Special constructors
    Point(const std::initializer_list<double>& il, types t = types::au) : type(t){
        assert((il.size() == 3) && "\nDynamic Assert: Only 3 elements allowed\n");
        std::copy_n(il.begin(), 3, coordinate.begin());
    }
    Point(const double x, const double y, const double z, types t = types::au) : type(t) {
        coordinate[0] = x; coordinate[1] = y; coordinate[2] = z;
    }
    Point(const double(&c)[3], types t = types::au) : type(t) {
        std::copy_n(std::begin(c), 3, coordinate.begin());
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Point& p) {
        return os << p.coordinate[0] << '\t' << p.coordinate[1] << '\t' << p.coordinate[2];
    }
    // Special assignment
    Point& operator = (const std::initializer_list<double>& il) {
        assert((il.size() == 3) && "\nDynamic Assert: Only 3 elements allowed\n");
        std::copy_n(il.begin(), 3, coordinate.begin());
        return *this;
    }
    Point& operator = (const double(&c)[3]) {
        std::copy_n(std::begin(c), 3, coordinate.begin());
        return *this;
    }

};
int main() {
    Point p1({ 1,2,3 });
    std::cout << "p1:\t" << p1 << '\n';

    Point p2({ 4,5,6 }, types::au);
    std::cout << "p2:\t" << p2 << '\n';

    Point p3( 7,8,9 );
    std::cout << "p3:\t" << p3 << '\n';

    Point p4( 10,11,12, types::au);
    std::cout << "p4:\t" << p4 << '\n';

    double d5[3] = { 13,14,15 };
    Point p5(d5);
    std::cout << "p5:\t" << p5 << '\n';

    double d6[3] = { 16,17,18 };
    Point p6(d6, types::au);
    std::cout << "p6:\t" << p6 << '\n';

    Point p7(p6);
    std::cout << "p7:\t" << p7 << '\n';

    Point p8;
    p8 = p7;
    std::cout << "p8:\t" << p8 << '\n';

    Point p9(19, 20, 21);
    Point p10(std::move(p9));
    std::cout << "p10:\t" << p10 << '\n';

    Point p11(22,23,24);
    Point p12{};
    p12 = (std::move(p11));
    std::cout << "p12:\t" << p12 << '\n';

    Point p13{};
    p13 = { 25,26,27 };
    std::cout << "p13:\t" << p13 << '\n';

    Point p14{};
    double d14[3] = { 28,29,30 };

    p14 = d14;
    std::cout << "p14:\t" << p14 << '\n';
}
```